# Enabling Push Status Messages on iOS 9 (APS/PC Logging)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I suddenly started having problems receiving push notifications to my application targeting iOS 9.0+ yesterday - now they're working fine again without a single code line change in the app or on the notifications provider server (anyone happened to witness the same? / to know if Apple might have had some kind of APN services outage yesterday?)

Anyway, I tried debugging the problem using the steps described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG24 in the *Enabling Push Status Messages on iOS* section but I was unable to install the "APS/PC Logging" tool to my iPhone 6s / iOS 9.3.1 - I sent the provided file *PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig* to the iPhone via an email attachment as suggested but when I tried to open it, I received an "Invalid Profile" error message.

Hence my questions: **Is it possible to install the "APS/PC Logging" tool to iPhone 6s / iOS 9 and debug push notification logs that way?**

(according to the Document Revision History, the last modification in the Apple document linked above was made on 2014-10-01, i.e. before iOS 9 was launched so the instructions and/or the file might be outdated).

Thank you very much in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got back to this issue after a longer while and I'm glad to find out that even though nobody answered the question here, there's been an update made to the "Troubleshooting Push Notifications" technical note available at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG24

According to the Document Revision History, there have been several modifications described as "Updated for iOS 8 and later. Refreshed logging profile." dated a couple of days after I asked my question here. I downloaded the new version of the tn2265_PersistentConnectionLogging.zip file and can confirm that it is now possible to install the tool into an iPhone running iOS 9.3.4 and capture some logs.

(Not sure if my question could have triggered the update or if it was merely a lucky coincidence - anyway, I'm glad that it's working again.)